# Eonasdan datetimepicker for bootstrap 3 in xPages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm having a problem with the bootstrap dateTimePicker control in my xpage application and I suspect this is to do with the way xPages generates a control id.

The following code works fine without an id on the inputText element.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fPath/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fPath/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RfPath/bootstrap-datetimepicker-3.0.0/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fPath/bootstrap-datetimepicker-3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' data-datetimepicker="true">
    <xp:inputText styleClass="form-control timePicker">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="time" timeStyle="short" />
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

As soon as I add an id back in I receive the following error when clicking away/out of the control:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: _id1

the id is required to map the data back to the document but I am not actually using it to attach the datetimepicker - I am using a class for this:

```
$('.timePicker').each(function(i,el){SHARED.timePickerOpen(el)}) 

SHARED = {
    timePickerOpen: function(el){
        $(el).datetimepicker({
            pickDate: false,
            pickTime: true,
            useCurrent: true,
            minuteStepping:5  
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE #1:

Sounds like there's a bit of misunderstanding going on so I'll try to explain further...

- In testing, I wrote the code in pure html giving the field an ID and
  it works fine.
- If I use an xpage field (where domino generates the ID
  using colons) the date picker fails with the error described above.
- I do not use the ID to bind the event to the field, I use a class get
  the field then bind the datetimepicker control to it.

The problem appears to be the datetimepicker using the field id. Even though I obtain the field through the class name (Not the id) the datetimepicker code seems to want to use an id if one is found in the field. The datetimepicker binds to the field without any problems. When you attempt to select a time the model box displays and allows you to select a time, the error occurs when you try to click away from the field to close the model time control.

Comment: Neil, if I am understanding correctly, you are saying that the control won't work unless you specifiy an ID and not a Class.  I don't think this is true.  Maybe this might help, this is a blog post I wrote a year ago where I'm using a datepicker and bootstrap 2, but maybe it might help. http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/06/datepickers-in-bootstrap-that-are.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting plugin. I created a sample page to see if I can get it to integrate with an XPage and if I get the same error. After doing what I describe below I got it to run without the issues you reported.

As described in the docs, I've added the plugin and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to a database, and used the sample code [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to build a simple demo page. In the database I am using the [Bootstrap4XPages](http://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org/) plugin (March release), so Bootstrap 3.1.1 is already loaded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
  xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
  xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script
        src="momentjs-2.7.0/moment.min.js"
        clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script
        src="eonasdan-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
        clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>
    <xp:styleSheet
        href="eonasdan-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>

<xp:div
    xp:key="facetMiddle">

    <p>
        This page uses&#160;
        <a
            href="https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker">Eonasdan's Bootstrap DateTimePicker</a>
        .
    </p>

    <div
        class="col-sm-6">
        <div
            class="form-group">
            <div
                class='input-group date'
                id='datetimepicker1'>

                <xp:inputText
                    id="inputText1"
                    styleClass="form-control">
                    <xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:convertDateTime
                            type="both"
                            timeStyle="short" />
                    </xp:this.converter>
                </xp:inputText>
                <span
                    class="input-group-addon">
                    <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</xp:div>

<xp:scriptBlock
    id="scriptBlock1">

    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

</xp:view>
```

Opening the XPage for the first time gave me a familiar error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I've seen that one before: newer jQuery plugins try to use its AMD loader, but that doesn't play well with the Dojo implementation in XPages. There are 2 workarounds that I know of:

1. Use [Sven Hasselbach's method](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1181) to load the (JavaScript) resources before Dojo.
2. Change the source code of the library you're using. This method is not perfect too, but the one I prefer. In the JavaScript file (in this case named `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` you need to find the lines that determine if it can use the AMD loader. They can mostly be found at the beginning or end of a JavaScript file.

Here's the code you're looking for in bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:

```
; (function (factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD is used - Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery', 'moment'], factory);
} else {
    // AMD is not used - Attempt to fetch dependencies from scope.
    if (!jQuery) {
        throw 'bootstrap-datetimepicker requires jQuery to be loaded first';
    } else if (!moment) {
        throw 'bootstrap-datetimepicker requires moment.js to be loaded first';
    } else {
        factory(jQuery, moment);
    }
}
}
```

We then disable (or remove; your choice) the AMD part:

```
; (function (factory) {
//if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD is used - Register as an anonymous module.
//    define(['jquery', 'moment'], factory);
//} else {
    // AMD is not used - Attempt to fetch dependencies from scope.
    if (!jQuery) {
        throw 'bootstrap-datetimepicker requires jQuery to be loaded first';
    } else if (!moment) {
        throw 'bootstrap-datetimepicker requires moment.js to be loaded first';
    } else {
        factory(jQuery, moment);
    }
//}
}
```

A live demo can be found [here](http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/dateTimePicker.xsp).

Comment: Fantastic! Works without any problems now. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

You should never try to hard code the ID that Domino assigns to a particular element.  If you need to use the ID to make something work, then this utility by Mark Roden works very well: 
http://xomino.com/2012/02/02/jquery-selector-function-for-xpages-xidinputtext1/

Also its dojo version: http://xomino.com/2012/02/28/x-update-for-dojo/

Just include this is a clientside script library, or reference directly using the script tag.

Comment: Hi Steve, I wasn't trying to hard code the ID. I have already tried x$ but obtaining the field isn't the problem. Its what the datetimepicker does with the jQuery object that causes the problem. (see my update above)

Comment: Your right, I didn't quite understand the question.  Looks like you got an excellent answer from Mark