# Charting on xpages with morris.js

Tags: javascript, charts, xpages

There are many easily implementable and **FREE** charting components around. But running them in xPages is a pain. 
I've tried [morrisjs](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html) but raphael.js conflicts with dojo. I'm getting a javascript error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined
```

Disabling dojo solves this problem but I'm losing all other dojo functionality which sucks.

I've put this line on beforePageLoad to disable dojo

```
facesContext.getRequestParameters().setJsLibrary(0);
```

How can I overcome this problem?

This might be off topic but I'm ok with other charting solutions which can be implemented on xpages easily and freely.

Comment: Have you tried Google?  I'm not trying to be smart but there have been blog posts on this.  I forget if any video hit NotesIn9 yet. But there are articles out there on graphing.  morrisjs MIGHT work if you load it before Dojo.  Use the headTag and make sure CSS aggregation is on for that I believe.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to make a decent chart for days. All i found was ugly charts made by dojox charting. But loading scripts before dojo is a great tip. Now I can display the chart and can use refresh option.

Comment: There's another workaround to deal with the AMD loader issue. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307884/eonasdan-datetimepicker-for-bootstrap-3-in-xpages. Not pretty, but works like a charm!

Comment: Yes I've used sven's method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Raphael doesn't comply to the shared practices of module loading. The usual hack is to load it as first module.

The better solution is to use the AMD (that's the loading convention) compatible version of Raphael.

Details are here: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/540

Comment: AMD module didn't seem to work. error : "define is not defined"

Comment: Provide a code sample. Did you get the patched version? Just checking: it is all csjs

Comment: My personal favorite is d3js. Once you got over the learning curve, there are no limits to what you can do. There are also abstractions for "classical charting" on top of d3js (Auntie Google knows them)

Comment: I've downloaded it from https://github.com/pajtai/raphael-amd.
d3js is a harsh mistress indeed, as once a wise man said :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the charting libraries that are included with Dojo and therefore already included?   I am currently using them with good results. I first found a good example at [OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/YouAtNotes%20xCharting/summary)

And here is an excellent [tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Dojox_Charting_for_XPages).

I also have used the [Java charts](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Java%20Charts) also from OpenNTF but found the Dojox version to be a bit more flexible and less memory intensive for the Xpage.

Comment: That component is unmaintained and very buggy. And visually eye bleeding.

Comment: There were just updated based on 9.0.  As far as the eye bleeding part, the examples are fairly ordinary but can be improved on.