# XPages Is it possible loading external javascript libraries via AMD loader?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, xpages

In Domino 9 dojo comes with the AMD loader which seems to be interfering with loading of external javascript libraries eg Jquery Mobile, Fullcalendar.

The quick solution is to load these external libraries before the dojo libraries. But this requires the Xpage property: "Use runtime optimized Javascript and CSS resources" to be set.

The problem with this is that images referenced in compressed css files will break. Eg font-awesome, jqueryui.

This is a major flaw in the product that these references have to be recoded in the css files for it to work.

So the question is can eg fulcalendar and it's dependencies be loaded via AMD in Xpages so we don't have to recode all css files referencing images?

Comment: Great question. I don't have an answer but here's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24324497/785061

Comment: Yes Thanks that will work. Tried it and seems to work for fullcalendar also.

Answer (score 0):

What exatly is your problem with loading jquery. I am loading jquery and other js libraries like select2, dgrowl, jgrid without any problems

Answer (score 0):

When using the "Use runtime optimized Javascript and CSS resources" setting, there are some additional options you can set directly in xsp.properties to stop aggregation of CSS files like font-awesome.  In this instance use 'xsp.resources.aggregate.css=false' and you will be good to go.

See http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/xpages-performance-dojo-widgets-and-resource-aggregation.htm for full details of all of the options.