# loading a javascript library and not getting an object returned

Tags: xpages

I am trying to load a javascript library in XPages.

Normally in HTML the reference looks as followed:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

which gives me a Hammer object in the DOM which I can work further with.

In XPages I have made the following setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" disableTheme="true"
    dojoForm="false" dojoTheme="false" dojoParseOnLoad="false"
    createForm="false">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
</xp:view>
```

alternatively:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" disableTheme="true" dojoForm="false" dojoTheme="false" dojoParseOnLoad="false" createForm="false">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:headTag tagName="script">
            <xp:this.attributes>
                <xp:parameter name="script" value="text/javascript" />
                <xp:parameter name="src" value="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js" />
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
    </xp:this.resources>
</xp:view>
```

But the Hammer object is not present in the DOM!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From first look what you are doing just loads the library.  You then need script to call it.

Comment: Indeed my answer below is incorrect. I will remove, even without calling it in a script, you can still should be able to call it manually in the browser console.

Comment: hammer.js uses AMD and therefore conflicts with Dojo. See this answer on how to remove AMD loading from hammer.js: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24324497/785061

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hammer.js uses AMD. Here's a snippet from the hammer.js source code where AMD is used:

```
if (typeof define == TYPE_FUNCTION && define.amd) {
    define(function() {
        return Hammer;
    });
} else if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = Hammer;
} else {
    window[exportName] = Hammer;
}
```

Unfortunately AMD loading conflicts with Dojo in XPages. See [this answer on how to remove AMD loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24324497/785061).

In your case you need to download hammer.js, change the AMD loading part, add it to your nsf and then load the script from your nsf instead.

You remove the AMD loading part by changing the code in hammer.js to for instance this:

```
//if (typeof define == TYPE_FUNCTION && define.amd) {
//    define(function() {
//        return Hammer;
//    });
//} else if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) {
if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = Hammer;
} else {
    window[exportName] = Hammer;
}
```

Comment: Hi Per, sounds like you have experienced similar problems before. Your approach works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to use the AMD loader which is a part of Dojo on newer versions of Domino.

This code implements the basic example from the hammer.js documentation (I'm only using jQuery for the ready function):

```
require({
    async: true, 
    aliases: [['jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'],
             ['Hammer', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.4/hammer.min.js']]
}, ['jquery', 'Hammer'], function(jq, Hammer){
    $(function() {
        var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');

        // create a simple instance
        // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
        var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

        // listen to events...
        mc.on("panleft panright tap press", function(ev) {
            myElement.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
        });
    });
});
```

Then just add the code to your xpage in a script tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="./css/basicImpl.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script src="./js/basicImpl.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <div id="myElement"></div>
</xp:view>
```

I'm also using the stylesheet from the example:

```
#myElement {
    background: silver;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 30px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things in no particular order:

- You can test that the script is loaded by using Chrome Dev Tools, and go to console. You can then put script in to call the hammer code. If the script isn't loaded then you will get an error.  Your script *might* already be loaded.
- Verify with the Hammer js site that you are loading the script properly
- Try putting your code in the `onClientLoad` event which just loads client code.
- Put the Hammer.js code into your NSF, to make sure you do not have connection issues to github.  Use Package Explorer and put the files in the WebContent/js folder. Put any CSS in the WebContent/CSS folder

Comment: for eg I set: <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {
 var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
 var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
});]]></xp:this.value>
 </xp:scriptBlock> but then I get the message ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined
 
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

Comment: onClient event isn't that for XSP?

Comment: it is for clientside script, I want to delete my answer, and when I push delete, it asks if I want to delete post, which of course I don't want to do.

Comment: But your script block should do the same thing.

Comment: hammer.js uses AMD and therefore conflicts with Dojo, See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24324497/785061

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten  I think you should put that in an answer since it sounds like it could be the root cause