# How to include Vue.js framework to XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages

Having problem including the Vue.js Framework to my XPages project, after using the below script to include i keep geting the error can not find New Vue

```
<xp:script src="vue/Vue.js" clientSide="true">  </xp:script>
```

Comment: Most likely because Vue uses AMD loading. Check SO for solutions to this.

Comment: SO? where would i check that ?

Comment: SO==Stack Overflow :-) See for instance my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483034/785061

Answer (score 0):

you can doing it by call it from theme like

```
<!-- This VUE DEVELOPMENT -->
<resource>
    <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
    <href>js/vue.development.js</href>
</resource>
<!-- This VUE DEVELOPMENT -->
```