# Xpages and videojs

Tags: xpages, video.js

Has anyone been able to get Domino 9 xpages to work with videojs ?
I project where I need a landing page to direct client to a CDN streaming from Wowza Streaming Engine.

Comment: FYI: Heiko Voigt has made a working example in the HCL forum: https://hclpnpsupport.hcltech.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b71517971bba98d0beab64e6ec4bcbb6

Comment: Ran across some weird, when the videojs is load through the headtag all the xpages event are not rendered.  I used headtag on other project like leaflet and D3 didn't have this problem.

Comment: It could be because videojs uses AMD loading

Comment: Yes I ran into that before, just got to remember how to fix that.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483034/785061

Comment: I used this https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together  to template disable and then enable.