# Bootstrap sidebar in XPages won't collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, sidebar

I'm having trouble getting a collapsible bootstrap sidebar to display correctly in XPages.  I found a simple example at bootstrapious.com, adapted the code for an XPage, and it almost works.  The button to collapse the sidebar doesn't do anything.  I am using Domino V12 and Designer V12, along with the built-in Bootstrap4 theme.  The bootstrapious code includes its own .css file, along with some .css and .js for Font Awesome.  I've tried removing those .css and .js files to check for conflicts.  Obviously, they made the page look worse, but didn't help the collapse button to work. So I put them back in and below is the entire page.  Is there some simple thing I've overlooked?  It works fine in an HTML file, but not in XPages.  One other interesting piece to the puzzle: If I start with a narrow browser window, the sidebar starts collapsed, but the button still won't expand it.

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/style2.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script
            src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script
            src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com" target="_blank">bootsrapious</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme: "minimal"
            });

            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
                $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
        });
    </script>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript file popper.min.js uses AMD which conflicts with Dojo in XPages. See this answer for a solution on how to disable AMD in order to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483034/785061

Comment: Thanks, Henrik, for setting me on the path to knowledge.  I did some more research on the AMD issue and tried several possible solutions that did not require me to edit the popper.js file.  The one that worked best for our app was found at OpenNTF:  https://openntf.org/xsnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together