# JSPDF-autotable : jsPDF is not defined

Tags: xpages

Trying to give the possibility to generate a pdf in xpages
The code I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:this.resources>
<xp:script src="generate.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jspdf.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>

<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<table id="basic-table" >
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>First name</th>
  <th>Last name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>IP-address</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td align="right">1</td>
  <td>Donna</td>
  <td>Moore</td>
  <td>dmoore0@furl.net</td>
  <td>China</td>
  <td>211.56.242.221</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td>Janice</td>
      <td>Henry</td>
      <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
      <td>Ukraine</td>
      <td>38.36.7.199</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td>Ruth</td>
      <td>Wells</td>
      <td>rwells2@constantcontact.com</td>
      <td>Trinidad and Tobago</td>
      <td>19.162.133.184</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>Ray</td>
      <td>jray3@psu.edu</td>
      <td>Brazil</td>
      <td>10.68.11.42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Stephens</td>
      <td>jstephens4@go.com</td>
      <td>United States</td>
      <td>47.32.129.71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Nichols</td>
      <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
      <td>18.186.38.37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

I'm getting an error in the console :

Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
    at generate (generate:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test_pdf2.xsp:20)
generate @ generate:3
onclick @ test_pdf2.xsp:20

and line 3 of generate.js = var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt');

When I have a look at the sources I can see under js the 2 libraries

What's wrong ?

Comment: The order of js-files matter. jspdf.min.js needs to be loaded first if generate.js depends on it.

Comment: any idea how to load it first ?

Comment: Just move the generate.js script-block further down in the HTML (under the jspdf blocks). Although if this line 3 is run on click, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsPDF uses AMD. Here's a snippet from the jspdf.min.js source code where AMD is used:

```
function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(e)
```

Unfortunately AMD loading conflicts with Dojo in XPages. See [this answer on how to remove AMD loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24324497/785061).

You need to change the AMD loading part by changing the code in jspdf.min.js to this:

```
function"==typeof define&&false?define(e)
```

jspdf.plugin.autotable.js uses AMD too. Here you need to replace `define.amd` with `false` too.

Comment: Made this change. Now I'm getting another error: Uncaught TypeError:doc.autoTableHtmlToJson is not a function, at line 5 of generate.js and that line is : var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("basic-table")); Is there some other dependencie ?

Comment: Sorry, it is working. It seems my browser didn't picked up the change in jspdf.plugin.autotable.js Must have been chached somewhere ...